# Magento 2 Problem with arguments in di.xml

Tags: magento2, exception, developer-mode, setup-di-compile

The problem is this: I have a module, which passes arguments from di.xml to a class. Deploy mode is a developer.

When I make changes in any arbitrary module or install a new module, and subsequently run `bin/magento setup:upgrade`. Then when I open the front page, which uses this module, I get the error for this module:

> (BadMethodCallException): Missing required argument

I was lead to believe that developer mode `setup:di:compile` is not necessary, but I'd like to have this confirmed. It seems to me a little strange, cause unless I run `setup:di:compile` this error keeps propping up.

Comment: " lead to believe that in developermode setup:di:compile is not necessary" this is true. you might have to delete the "generated" folder tho.

Comment: why do you think "bin/magento setup:upgrade" will solve your problem?

Comment: Can you please share the code of di.xml and respencted class here.